# Restrict Gutenberg Editor for custom post type wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I need to create my own custom post type and want to limit Gutenberg editor for my post type(only) and use WordPress editor in this post type.
how can limit this plugin for my cpt??

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter to disable Gutenberg for all post type with the exception of you custom post type name.

```
/**
 * Disabling the Gutenberg editor all post types except post.
 *
 * @param bool   $can_edit  Whether to use the Gutenberg editor.
 * @param string $post_type Name of WordPress post type.
 * @return bool  $can_edit
 */
function gutenberg_can_edit_post_type_83744857( $can_edit, $post_type ) {
    $gutenberg_supported_types = array( 'post' ); //Change this to you custom post type
    if ( ! in_array( $post_type, $gutenberg_supported_types, true ) ) {
        $can_edit = false;
    }
    return $can_edit;
}
add_filter( 'gutenberg_can_edit_post_type', 'gutenberg_can_edit_post_type_83744857', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: you can also use 'show_in_rest' => true, argument while you register your post type because by the addition of   show_in_rest key and set it to true via your custom post type. You can check detailed description at https://www.cloudways.com/blog/gutenberg-wordpress-custom-post-type/

Answer (score 2):

For those finding this question after WordPress 5.0 was released, you can turn off the Block Editor (f.k.a Gutenberg) for certain post types by using the *use_block_editor_for_post_type* filter like so:

```
add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post_type', function( $useBlockEditor, $postType ){

    if( $postType == 'your-custom-post-type-slug' )
        return false;
    return $useBlockEditor;

}, 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by plugin or custom code.

1. Plugin [Disable Gutenberg](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-gutenberg/)
2. Code, add it to functions.php

> ```
> function mh_disable_gutenberg($is_enabled, $post_type) {
>
>   if ($post_type === 'news') return false; // change news to your post type
>
>   return $is_enabled;
>
> }
> add_filter('gutenberg_can_edit_post_type', 'mh_disable_gutenberg', 10, 2);
> ```